# JQuery unbind issue

Tags: jquery, forms, unbind

I have some jquery that prevents a couple of select fields from being changed when a check box is ticked. This is working okay but I can't seem to get the unbind to work. I need the selects to work again when the checkbox is unticked.

```
$("input#same").live('click', function () {
    if ($("input#same").is(':checked')) {
        // Checked, copy values 
        $("input#shipping_first_name").val($("input#first_name").val()).attr("readonly", true);
        $("input#shipping_last_name").val($("input#last_name").val()).attr("readonly", true);
        $("input#shipping_address").val($("input#address").val()).attr("readonly", true);
        $("input#shipping_address2").val($("input#address2").val()).attr("readonly", true);
        $("input#shipping_city").val($("input#city").val()).attr("readonly", true);
        $("select#shipping_state").val($("select#state").val()).bind("change", function () {
            $("select#shipping_state").val($("select#state").val())
        });
        $("input#shipping_zip").val($("input#zip").val()).attr("readonly", true);
        $("select#shipping_country_code").val($("select#country_code").val()).bind("change", function () {
            $("select#shipping_country_code").val($("select#country_code").val())
        });
    } else {
        // Clear on uncheck 
        $("input#shipping_first_name").val("").removeAttr("readonly");
        $("input#shipping_last_name").val("").removeAttr("readonly");
        $("input#shipping_address").val("").removeAttr("readonly");
        $("input#shipping_address2")..val("").removeAttr("readonly");
        $("input#shipping_city").val("").removeAttr("readonly");
        $("select#shipping_state").val("").unbind("change");
        $("input#shipping_zip").val("").removeAttr("readonly");
        $("select#shipping_country_code").val("").unbind("change");
    }
});
$('#order').live('submit', function () {
    $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
});
```

Comment: You have most probably not added an empty string in the list of select box values, which is why the val('') code is not working. Alternatively, you can simply set the selection to first option in the select box if val() does not work at all.

Comment: don't you have an error here: $("input#shipping_address2")..val("").removeAttr("readonly"); Maybe, that's the point why you further javascript doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .die() when you attached event using live. Please refer to here:http://api.jquery.com/die/

Comment: It was the extra . error as ikostia said. All working now! Thanks